# multiply the every second digit in list in python

Tags: python, list

I've tried to get numbers' list between 0 and100,000. and then i want to multiply every second digits of the list. I have no idea how to get the ervery second digit of the numbers.

```
def breakandSum():
  if 0<=x<100000:
      digits=(map(int,str(x)))
      return digits
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you are trying to do (possibly with some example input/output)?

Comment: @Amiya Seems the question is regarding how to extract a specific digit in base 10. An answer on how to do this is posted below. Please let me know if this answers the intent of the question.

Comment: if the input number is 4567,and i need to return the list[4,5,6,7,],then multiply 5*7=35.and i do not know how to get the 5 and 7 then multiply then

Comment: @Amiya Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the second digit from the right in base 10, you would first mod the number by 100 to truncate the leading digits, then take the integer result and divide by the integer 10 to truncate the trailing digits.

Here's a quick example where x = 4567 which extracts the second base 10 digit from the right, or the "tens" digit, which is "6" in this example:

```
>>> x = 4567
>>> x = x % 100
>>> x = x / 10
>>> print x
6
```

If you wanted to put all the digits in a list, you could just extract the right-most digit, append it to the list, then truncate and continue the loop as shown here:

```
>>> x = 4567
>>> xdigit = []
>>> while x > 0:
...     xdigit.append(x % 10)
...     x = x / 10
...
>>> print xdigit
[7, 6, 5, 4]
>>>
```

From here you can then get every second digit using a list comprehension and filter:

```
>>> every_other_digit = [xdigit[i] for i in filter(lambda j: j % 2 == 0, range(len(xdigit)))]
>>> print every_other_digit
[7, 5]
```

Which if you need to multiply these digits you can now just iterate over this list to get the final product:

```
>>> answer = 1
>>> for k in every_other_digit: answer *= k
...
>>> print answer
35
```

Comment: you function makes the list of the numbers, but i want to know how to multiply the every second number of the list.

Comment: @Amiya Updated the answer to then multiply by every other number in the list.

Answer (score 0):

There is a more concise way of doing it:

```
digitSum = sum(x * 2 for x in list(map(int, str(num)))[::2])
```

Where:

`str(num)` turns `num` into a string

`list(map(int, str(num)))` for every element in string turn it back to an int and put it in a list

`list(...)[::2]` for every other element in the list starting from the leftmost element

`x * 2 for x in list(...)[::2]` for each element in the list multiply it by 2

`sum(...)` add every element from the iteration

Edit: sorry I thought you wanted to multiply each by a specific number if you want to multiply every other you just go:

```
import math

digitSum = math.prod(x for x in list(map(int, str(num)))[::2])
```